# Cappuccino - take an image from a CPView

Tags: cappuccino, objective-j

I have a CPView with some children (CPImageView's, CPTextField's, etc) and I would like to know if it's possible to take an screenshot of that parent view.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, not out of the box... remember you're still in the browser.

Now, depending on how bad you want this...
A while back someone wrote a generic DOM parser than rendered out the current DOM on to a canvas. It was pretty immature though.

Luckily Cappuccino generally uses just some absolutely positioned divs, and background colors/images. Which means if you wanted to write your own parser, it might not be as hard as it sounds.